# How to add only executing assembly in CompositionContainer without add AssemblyCatalog

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, mef

Good day.

I need to be added executing assembly in CompositionContainer (MEF) without add AssemblyCatalog. Since this assembly has 20 reference on other project.

At now, I'm use next solution:

```
AssemblyCatalog asCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
AggregateCatalog agCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();
agCatalog.Catalogs.Add(asCatalog);
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm not sure you can... why is this an issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After watching the source code MEF, the issue resolved itself. AssemblyCatalog  imports only the specified assembly.

http://mef.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#redist/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/Hosting/AssemblyCatalog.cs